# Laravel Lumen error 500 at subdomain

Tags: php, apache, lumen

I get white screen (`500 Internal Server Error`) when deploy a "Lumen app" to a "subdomain" (LAMP Ubuntu 14.04 at Digital Ocean). In local environment everything works fine (XAMPP for Windows).

My `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Edit:**

There's no log file at `/storage/logs`. I used Git to pull the project into a sobdomain (withouth log file 'cause `.gitignore`). `/storage` has 0777 permissions.

The project is at bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/adlnetworks/adl-notificaciones (https://bitbucket.org/adlnetworks/adl-notificaciones.git)

Please use `Develop` (default) branch. 
I don't know what's wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there any error log? If yes, please edit your question and add output of error log there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was OK, Lumen supports subdomains by default. I Forgot install composer dependencies at production server.

Greetings.